# Change the background color using a loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to change the background color when the button is clicked. But instead of the color being changed sequentially when I click the button, it directly changes to the last one. How do I fix it by using for loop only.

```js
but.addEventListener("click", clickfunction);

function clickfunction() {
  color = arr.shift();
  arr.push(color);
  bgcolor.style.background = color;
  but.style.color = color;
  but.innerText = color;
  comming[0].style.background = --color;
};
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Click edit, then scroll down and "edit above snippet"  - paste relevant Script HTML and CSS to provide a [mcve] - we need your elements and your color array

Comment: You need a setTimeout to allow the DOM to change. Now your loop is too fast for the DOM. Also I assume you want to change the backgroundColor

Comment: Also please [look for dupes](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+change+background+color+loop) before asking

Comment: Could you tell us what is stored in **color** variable? Because last line with **--color;** looks very suspicious

Comment: Answer : https://jsfiddle.net/donqq/f2bda7jp/23/